# Where to ask question about windows firewall?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation

The following question was blocked on Stack Overflow because it is off-topic. So my question (hopefully not off-topic here) is :

Where am I allowed to ask the following question?

> How can I block all connections to port 80 from all IP's other than localhost via windows firewall ? I am using windows 2012 R2 and want to allow only connections from localhost on this port.
>   My localhost translates to ::1 and when I add ::1 in a scope section the following error appears: "An unspecified, multicast, broadcast or loopback IPv6 address was specified."

Maybe it is trivial question for someone, but I am really stuck with it and want to know an answer. My intention is not to spam Stack Exchange so please answer me where to ask or if it is not possible to ask please state it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question can be posted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). As their [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) says:

> Ask about...
>
> Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking

Comment: +1 Thanks. I did not know about such site untill now.